content trasfer encoding for email attachment causing unwated character at line end
I have a HTML file and it's in UTF-16 LE BOM and I am using Java with simple java mail library (which uses jakarta mail internally) to send the mail. When I send the mail by attaching the HTML file, the receiver of the mail see some extra character ਍ഀ at every line ending in the attachment file.
I checked the raw email messages and the attachment is being added having header as Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable also Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8;.
While sending email I am only detecting MIME type of the file and then give byte[], name of the attachment and detected MIME type to the simple java mail library, I assume that rest work is done either by simeple java mail library or by jakarta mail itself.
questions are:

why library is setting charset as UTF-8 where the file is in UTF-16? Don't they do the detection part?

Also, rather than depending on library if I set header as Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 then file is being send nicely without any extra character at the end.

So, my program being generic to send any email with any type of attachment how I can detect which is most suitable Content-Transfer-Encoding for any type of attachment?


I'm not familiar with either library, but I had a look at Simple Java Mail and couldn't find support for any encoding other than UTF-8. You might have to use Jakarta Mail directly, though I may be wrong. By the way, it would help if you added some code to show how you're creating the email.
